# Embedding JSON in Query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a users table and a notes table and I am trying to figure out the best way forward so I can edit the data easily and show it on my front-end.  I was considering storing the notes as JSON in the notes table but figured that may be harder to edit say the title of a note later.

```
CREATE TABLE users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT UNIQUE)
CREATE TABLE notes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, content TEXT UNIQUE, user_id FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id))

INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES('John')
INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES('Jane')

INSERT INTO notes(user_id, content) VALUES(1, "John's 1st Note")
INSERT INTO notes(user_id, content) VALUES(1, "John's 2nd Note")
INSERT INTO notes(user_id, content) VALUES(2, "Jane's 1st Note")
```

I am trying to write a select statement that will return all of my users and group their notes together as JSON.  Something like this returned would be awesome:

```
[name:John,notes:[{id:1, content:"John's 1st Note"},{id:2, content:"John's 2nd Note"}],
name: Jane,notes: [{id:3, content:"Jane's 1st Note"}]]
```

I've tried looking at group_concat() and json_group_array() but I'm really struggling trying to get this data together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    users.name,
    json_group_array(json_object('id', notes.id, 'content', notes.content)) AS notes
FROM 
    users 
LEFT JOIN 
    notes ON users.id = notes.user_id
GROUP BY 
    users.id;
```